# Using SASS SCSS in .Net Core 5. How to install and use?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, sass, visual-studio-2019

I can't find any tutorials on how to install and use SASS in .net core 5. The tutorials i have read have always pointed towards a lower version of .Net Core, and the NUGET packages do not support .net 5.

Can anyone share any material how i can use SASS in my visual studio 2019 .net core 5.0 project please?

Answer (score 1):

I am noob but in visual studio there is Extensions menu where you just look for Sass compiler... So it should help you :)

[image]